# I would like to send Longitude and Latitude (Current location of mobile phone) to JSP page and store it to the MYSQL database

Tags: android

I would like to create android app which send the current location of mobile phone to JSP page and then store it into MySQL. By using the following code I got the location but how I can send Longitude and Latitude to JSP page.....

Here is code......

```
public class GPSMyListView extends Activity {

int increment = 4;
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
double Longitude,Latitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpsmy_list_view);

     myLocation.getLocation(getApplicationContext(), locationResult);
     boolean r = myLocation.getLocation(getApplicationContext(),locationResult);

     TextView Longi =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Longitude);
     TextView Lati =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Latitude);

     DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
     String formattedValue = decimalFormat.format(Longitude);

     Longi.setText(formattedValue);
     Lati.setText(formattedValue);
}

public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {

    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Longitude= location.getLongitude();
         Latitude= location.getLatitude();

          // updateDatabase();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THis is u r phone Location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("**************************************************");
        System.out.println(+Longitude);
        System.out.println("**************************************************");

    }
};


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gpsmy_list_view, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Here is I used this to send the longitude and latitude to my jsp page..... but it didn't work....

String l1= String.valueOf(Langitude);
String l2= String.valueOf(Latitude):

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

```
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8084/TrackPhone/login1.jsp");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Longitude", Longitude));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latitude", Latitude));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Comment: how you will access your jsp page in your app i.e are you using webview to show it?

Comment: thank you for attention...... I have created one JSP site in NetBeans .. and run it on localhost. Now I would like to send my Longitude and Latitude (which I got by using above code) to my this JSP page....

Comment: added answer, please check that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `HttpPost`, please use `HttpGet` and pass your parameter in query string like below:

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8084/TrackPhone/login1.jsp?Longitude="+Longitude+"&Latitude="+Latitude;

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

// add request header
//request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

System.out.println("Response Code : " +response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
{
    result.append(line);
}
```

In your `jsp` get this parameter like this:

```
Longitude: <%= request.getParameter("Longitude") %>
Latitude: <%= request.getParameter("Latitude") %>
```